# Limiting incoming OpenVPN client to the single local address

Tags: linux, router, vpn, routing, openvpn

I need to let someone connect to my LAN, using OpenVPN and connect them to Virtual machine at 192.168.1.5:5555. They must be strictly limited to be able to access only that VM and nothing else! My VPN server is running on Asus router. My VPNserver1 should keep working as before, and be separated from the above connection completely.

Basically everything works but I want to shield my existing network and devices from whoever uses this VPNserver2.

Here is my plan.

1. Create completely new set of certificates. At my router make a VPNServer2, changing its port to e.g. 1197 and VPN Subnet to e.g. 10.37.0.0. and allow Client <-> Client Push back to 192.168.3.7.
2. The remote WinXP PC will be 192.168.3.7, CN: ASD, and will be connecting using UltraVNC, having dynamic WAN IP
3. When they connect to VPNserver2, they must be allowed only to 192.168.1.5:5555

I do not know how to do point #3. Everything else should be under control. So how to let VPNserver2 be able to route only to this single one address at my network?

It is essential that I keep Client <-> Client Push back to 192.168.3.7 so that VM can print directly to their remote printer. But, even if someone is not certain about that detail, I would be bery gratefull for a reposonse how to do this route from vpn client to machine in question so I can experiment further.

Comment: So, nobody here can help me with a one or two lines of linux routing from 10.37.0.x to 192.168.1.5:5555?